# I wanna get a result of i/j . Like 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 3/5, 3, 5/3... Something like that. But none of my code works

Tags: list-manipulation

**None of this works,can anyone correct this?**

### 1st method

`j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
jase[i_, j_] := i/j`

### 2nd method

`i != j;
Table[i/j, j \[Element] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
 i \[Element] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}]`

### 3rd method

`jase[i_, j_] := 
Module[{}, i ≠ j; Element[{i, j}, List[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]; i/j]`

Comment: It's unclear what you want and none of this syntax is even close to valid Mathematica syntax. It looks like syntax from a very different language to me. Could you try to explain what you need or expect? What are the desired outputs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going through your attempts one by one:

#### Attempt 1

```
j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
jase[i_, j_] := i/j
```

What you are doing here is three things:

- You set the value of `j` to `{1, 3, ...}`
- You set the value of `i` to `{1, 3, ...}`
- You define a function `jase` that takes two arguments named `i` and `j` (no connection to the variables from before) that returns `i/j`. So e.g. `jase[3,4]` will return `3/4`

To fix it, a first attempt could be to call `jase[i,j]`:

```
jase[i, j]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

As we can see, this is not what we want. The problem is that `{...}/{...}` simply divides corresponding elements. To get all possible combinations, you can use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) (as shown by @kglr):

```
Outer[jase, i, j]
(* {{1, 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9}, {3, 1, 3/5, 3/7, 1/3},
    {5, 5/3, 1, 5/7, 5/9}, {7, 7/3, 7/5, 1, 7/9},
    {9, 3, 9/5, 9/7, 1}} *)
```

#### Attempt 2

```
i != j;
Table[i/j, j ∈ {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; i ∈ {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}]
```

You're doing two things:

- `i != j` simply returns itself without doing anything. You're suppressing that output with the `;`
- The syntax for the [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) expression is wrong. To specify that `i` and `j` should be elements of the list `{1, 3, ...}`, use `{i, {1, 3, ...}}`:

  ```
  Table[i/j, {j, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}}, {i, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}}]
  (* {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {1/3, 1, 5/3, 7/3, 3}, 
      {1/5, 3/5, 1, 7/5, 9/5}, {1/7, 3/7, 5/7, 1, 9/7}, 
      {1/9, 1/3, 5/9, 7/9, 1}} *)
  ```

#### Attempt 3

```
jase[i_, j_] := 
Module[{}, i ≠ j; Element[{i, j}, List[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]; i/j]
```

This one defines a function `jase` with two arguments, that does three things:

- Evaluate the expression `i ≠ j` (which does nothing on its own) and discard its result
- Evaluate the expression `Element[{i, j}, List[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]` (which does nothing on its own), and discard its result
- Evaluate the expression `i/j` (which stays unevaluated) and return its result

So calling `jase[1, 2]` gives for example:

```
jase[1, 2]
(* 1/2 *)
```

I don't think this one can be easily fixed

#### Discarding i==j

You'll notice that all the examples above return a bunch of ones, since the cases where `i==j` are not discarded. There are several ways to do this, see e.g. the answers of @kglr and @ChrisK. A solution that is more explicit could be the following:

```
jase[i_, j_] := i/j
jase[i_, i_] := Nothing

Outer[jase, Range[1, 9, 2], Range[1, 9, 2]]
(* {{1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9}, {3, 3/5, 3/7, 1/3}, {5, 5/3, 5/7, 5/9}, {7, 7/3, 7/5, 7/9}, {9, 3, 9/5, 9/7}} *)
```

This is essentially your first attempt with an additional case for `jase`: The second definition says "if both arguments are the same, then return [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html)". And `Nothing` is automatically removed from lists.

Comment: Nice pedagogical answer!

Comment: @Lukas Lang Thank you for detailed info first. `!=` means  `≠` . The problem here is that Mathematica can intepret `!=` into `≠` , but stackexchange.com can't do the same thing as Mathematica does

Comment: @kyle I am aware that `!=` and `≠` are the same thing in Mathematica - why do you mention it?

Comment: @Lucas Lang you told me `i` `!=` `j` simply returns itself without doing anything. It should add constraints to j and i

Comment: @kile `i != j` is the same as `i ≠ j`, which is again the same as `Unequal[i, j]`. The point is that just writing `i != j` somewhere does not magically force `i` to be different than `j`, that is not how Mathematica works. `i != j` becomes `True` or `False` if it's possible to decide, otherwise it will just stay unevaluted as `i != j`. But never does `Unequal` in itself cause any side-effects. You can e.g. look at the documentation of [`Unequal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html) to see that it has no such constraining functionality as you seem to be expecting it

Comment: @ Lucas Lang So how do u rule out `i/j ≠ 1`? Use `DeleteCases`? Is this the only way to achieve that?

Comment: `DeleteCases` is one way, although it's a bit indirect (you're not deleting cases where `i == j`, you're deleting cases with the same result as if `i == j`). See the last section in my answer for a different way using two definitions for `jase` and `Nothing`. Another way to write the two definitions that is maybe closer to what you're imagining is `jase[i_, j_] /; i != j := i/j` and `jase[_, _] := Nothing` - this uses [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) to restring the first definition to cases where `i != j`, while the second one is the default case

Comment: @Lucas Lang I don't think Condition  will work here.`jase[i_, j_] := i/j /; i != j
Outer[jase, Range[1, 9, 2], Range[1, 9, 2]] // 
  Flatten // DeleteDuplicates` The output is `{jase[1, 1], 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, 3, jase[3, 3], 3/5, 3/7, 5, 5/3, 
 jase[5, 5], 5/7, 5/9, 7, 7/3, 7/5, jase[7, 7], 7/9, 9, 9/5, 9/7, 
 jase[9, 9]}`

Comment: @Lucas Lang How can you remove `jase[1,1] ,jase[3,3] ,jase[5,5]...`?

Comment: kile, you forgot to add the second part of definition (`jase[_, _] := Nothing`)  in Lucas's comment; that is, use `ClearAll[jase];
jase[i_, j_] := i/j /; i != j ;
jase[_, _] := Nothing;
Outer[jase, Range[1, 9, 2], Range[1, 9, 2]] // 
  Flatten // DeleteDuplicates`

Answer (score 4):

How's this?

```
range = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[i/j, {i, range}, {j, range}]], 1]
(* {1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, 3, 3/5, 3/7, 1/3, 5, 5/3, 5/7, 5/9,
  7, 7/3, 7/5, 7/9, 9, 3, 9/5, 9/7} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
range = Range[1, 9, 2];

# / DeleteCases[range, #] & /@ range // Flatten
```

> {1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, 3, 3/5, 3/7, 1/3, 5, 5/3, 5/7, 5/9, 7, 7/3, 7/5, 7/9, 9, 3, 9/5, 9/7}

Additional alternatives:

```
Flatten @ MapIndexed[Drop] @ Outer[Divide, range, range]

MapIndexed[Apply[Sequence] @* Drop] @ Outer[Divide, range, range]

Tuples[foo[range, range]] /. foo[a_, a_] -> Nothing /. foo -> Divide

Join @@ Table[i/j, {i, range}, {j, DeleteCases[range, i]}]

Distribute[{range, range}, List, List, DeleteCases[{##}, 1] &, Divide]

Array[Divide, {1, 1} Length@range, {MinMax@range}, DeleteCases[Flatten[{##}], 1] &]
```

and a Halloween special:

```
☺ = range; 
## & @@@ (#/(☺ /. # -> (## &[])) & /@ ☺)
```

Comment: kglr,Great thanks to your effort in answering my question here. BTW, have you seen the comments made by Lucas Lang 17 hours ago? He tried to solve it with `Condition` . I don't think it works. You can see it in the response I made to his comments

Comment: @kile, pls see my comment under Lucas's answer.

Comment: Can you explain you code here? `Tuples[foo[range, range]] /. foo[a_, a_] -> Nothing /. foo -> Divide`

Comment: @kile, if we use `Tuples[Divide[range, range]]` , the function `Divide` is evaluated (and gives `{1,1,1,1,1}`) before `Tuples` gets to work.So instead I use `Tuples[foo[range, range]]` which gives `{foo[1, 1], foo[1, 3], foo[1, 5], foo[1, 7], foo[1, 9], foo[3, 1], 
 foo[3, 3], foo[3, 5], foo[3, 7], foo[3, 9], foo[5, 1], foo[5, 3], 
 foo[5, 5], foo[5, 7], foo[5, 9], foo[7, 1], foo[7, 3], foo[7, 5], 
 foo[7, 7], foo[7, 9], foo[9, 1], foo[9, 3], foo[9, 5], foo[9, 7], 
 foo[9, 9]}` then replace `foo` with `Divide` to get the ratios of all pairs.

Comment: Why was this not working?`i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
Tuples[jase[i, j]] /. jase[i_, j_] -> i/j`

Comment: How do u achieve this when  `jase[i_,j_]:=i^2+j` with `Tuples`?

Comment: @kile, for `i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; Tuples[jase[i, j]] /. jase[i_, j_] -> i/j` you need to change `Rule (->)` to [`RuleDelayed (:>)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html).

Comment: But why is `jase[i_,j_]:>Nothing` useless in this code below? `i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
Tuples[jase[i, j]] /. {jase[i_, j_] :> i/j, jase[i_, j_] :> Nothing}`

Comment: @kile, (1) when the first rule (`jase[i_, j_] :> i/j`)  is applied all elements of `Tuples[jase[i, j]]` are turned into integers or rationals; there is no element left that matches `jase[_,_]` so the second rule becomes irrelevant. (2) In general, when you have a list of rules with the same left-hand-side the first one is used to make the replacements (for each part of the input list the first rule that applies (the first rule whose lhs matches the the part)  replaces it with the expression on the rhs of the rule and that part is not processed again) so the later rules become irrelevant)

Comment: @kile, btw  you might consider posting some of the questions in the your comments as new questions (to get more detailed / better answers).

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
Divide @@@ Tuples[Range[1, 9, 2], 2] /. (1 :> Sequence[])
```

[`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) avoids need for `Flatten` with [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) or [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

Comment: @ ubpdqn Thanks. How can add`i` `!=` `j` as a constraint?

Comment: @kile, the replace rule at end removes all the 1s = j/j.

Comment: Have you seen the comments made by Lucas Lang 17 hours ago? He tried to solve it with`Condition` . I don't think it works. You can see it in the response I made to his comments

Comment: @kile sorry I did not. As with many things, one of the joys of MMA (WL) is that you can do the same thing in many ways. You choose the way that suits your needs (including scaling up, speed, aesthetics etc).  I think the other answers work well. I just added this as Tuple is sometimes useful. All the best.

Comment: ubpdqn
,Can you explain your Code ? How do you add i/j?

Comment: @kile Tuple just does the outer product of 2 copies of odd numbers 1 to 9. Divide creates the fractions.  (@@@ just applies Divide to lowest level). As I/j =1 for I=j, “/.(1:>Sequence[]), removes the 1s.

Comment: @ubpdqnHow do u achieve this when `jase[i_,j_]:=i^2+j` with Tuples?

Comment: @kile Tuple is just another way to do what the answers have done. I am not sure what your big picture goal is but I would suggest trying things and seeing. If you get stuck post another question with specific issue. To answer your specific question, Just use #1^2+#2& instead of Divide. Again just keep playing. You learn a lot from that.

Comment: `#1 = i` and `#2 =j`?  Is that what you are suggesting here?

Comment: It's not working. `i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
Tuples[jase[i, j]] /. jase -> #1^2 + #2 &`

Comment: @kile I am not sure your issue is. Perhaps post another Q. At present I am overwhelmingly busy and will not be able to help further. My apologies